# add graph inside last cell of plotly treemap

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, treemap

i have an treemap as shown in fig and the last cell contains some voltage data for every cell and i want to print the a line plot whenever i click on the last cell if possible can we do that inside the treemap and if not is there any alternative for that[image]

i want to show an lineplot for the last cell of the treemap whenever i click on the last cell